# Error: no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++

Even i have tried a lot  but i don't know where's error in my code. It seems just so easy.

```
enum Suit { none, clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades };
enum Symbol { none_, ace, king, queen, jack, ten, nine, eight, seven };

class Card
{
private:
    Suit suit_;
    Symbol symbol_;

public:

    Card(Suit suit, Symbol symbol)
    {
        suit_=suit;
        symbol_=symbol;
    };
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: What exactly does the error say, and which line does it indicate is wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and not for the error listed. Are you sure you copied + pasted it in correctly? You can [edit] your question if you need to add more information

Comment: Can you add the snippet wherein you are creating an object of "Card"

Answer (score 0):

Your class does not have a `default constructor`. It is not a problem in itself. However, if you try to call the non-exist `default constructor` the error will be shown. You probably doing something like this in other place (one of those lines is enough to throw that error):

```
Card x;
std::vector<Card> v(3);
auto x=std::make_shared<Card>();
//...and many others...
```

**Solution?**

If you really do not want that the `Card` being allocated without giving argument, you should not do this. Find the code that trying to allocate a `Card` object and alter it. BTW it is preferred to `delete` the `default constructor` in a clear statement like this:

```
class Card{
private:
    Suit suit_;
    Symbol symbol_;
public:
    Card()=delete;
    Card(Suit suit, Symbol symbol)
    {
        suit_=suit;
        symbol_=symbol;
    }
};
```

If you are OK with allocating objects from `Card` class with default values then add this instead:

```
class Card{
private:
    Suit suit_;
    Symbol symbol_;
public:
    Card()=default;
    //Or Card():suit_(some_value),symbol_(somevalue){}
    Card(Suit suit, Symbol symbol)
    {
        suit_=suit;
        symbol_=symbol;
    }
};
```

Comment: I like this answer, but: who knows if this will solve the OP's problem since not enough information was given (regardless, your answer is helpful), and I feel it would be nice to mention _why_ a default constructor wasn't generated

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your own constructor, under such cases, the compiler does not add the default constructor. Henceforth, if you are trying to create an object as mentioned below, you will end up with no default constructor error

`card obj;`   // Error

solution:

1) pass the arguments, while creating the object (`Most appropriate` as per the snippet):

example:

```
Suit suitenum = clubs;  
Symbol symnum = king;
Card obj(suitenum,symnum);
```

2) Define a default constructor:

```
class Card
{
    private:
        Suit suit_;
        Symbol symbol_;

    public:
        Card(){};

        Card(Suit suit, Symbol symbol)
        {
            suit_=suit;
            symbol_=symbol;
        };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

To cut it short and simple you just have to provide default constructor (no arguments).

```
Card()
{
}
```

The reason you require default constructor is you are using vector (container) of this type. (class). and for container classes, the contained class (card) must have the default constructor.